# Google maps API with targetSdkVersion 27

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Is there a release, or any way to use the google maps API with targetSdkVersion 27 or above? I'd like to add it to an existing project with target 27, but the latest version I could find (15.0.1) only works with target 26.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the problem was that I needed to define

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

manually, so the maps wouldn't try to use the old ones